# TODO in React w/ Redux

Tags: react.js, to-do-list, jsx, redux

Please critique my TODO App in React w/ Redux:

[image: Screenshot]

```
// React Component
const TodoApp = ({todos, inputText, onInputChange, onAdd, onDelete}) => {
    const numbers = range(todos.length);
    const zipped  = zip(numbers, todos);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>TODO!</h1>
            <ul>{zipped.map( (z) =>
                    <li key={z[0].toString()}>
                        {z[1].text}
                        <button onClick={() => onDelete(z[0])}>delete</button>
                    </li>
                )}
                <li>
                    <input type="text" value={inputText} onChange={onInputChange}/>
                    <button onClick={onAdd}>add</button>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
};

// Redux (State)
const ADD = 'ADD';
const UPDATE_INPUT_TEXT = 'UPDATE_INPUT_TEXT';
const DELETE='DELETE';

function todo(state = {todos: [], inputText: ""}, action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case ADD:
            return {
              todos: state.todos.concat( {
                text: state.inputText
              }),
              inputText: ''
            };
        case UPDATE_INPUT_TEXT:
            return {
                todos: state.todos,
                inputText: action.newInputText
            };
        case DELETE:
            const filtered = state.todos.filter( (e, index) => index !== action.index);
            return {
                todos: filtered,
                inputText: ''
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

const store = createStore(todo);

const renderTodo = () => {
    const st = store.getState();
    ReactDOM.render(
        <TodoApp todos={st.todos}
                 inputText={st.inputText}
                 onInputChange={event =>
                     store.dispatch({type: UPDATE_INPUT_TEXT, newInputText: event.target.value})
                 }
                 onAdd={() => store.dispatch({type: ADD})}
                 onDelete={(index) => store.dispatch({type: DELETE, index: index})}

        />,
        document.getElementById('root')
    )
};

store.subscribe(renderTodo);
renderTodo();
```

Comment: Questions rather general... code would appear to follow the rules to qualify as a Redux / React app. You should consider using [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) which provides nice store connect middleware and possibly looking at something like [immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) to ensure immutability in your store.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure of your environment (I'm going to assume you're using Node), and with this assumption, I want to address a few things starting with specific things, then more general:

**Specific**

1. You shouldn't be keeping `inputText` in the global store. This creates lots of store dispatches and updates which are completely unnecessary and costly. Instead, pass the input value once you want to add a todo. This would entail the use of state in `TodoApp` to control the input so you'd have to change to an ES6 class, but that's favorable to the unnecessary updating of the Redux store.
2. There's no need to do the two lines:

   ```
   const numbers = range(todos.length);
   const zipped  = zip(numbers, todos);
   ```

   You can shorten your `Array#map` callback to this without those two lines:

   ```
   {
     todos.map(({ text }, index) =>
       <li key={index}>
         {text}
         <button onClick={() => onDelete(index)}>delete</button>
       </li>
     )
   }
   ```

**General**

1. **Organization** - Separate your Redux reducers, actions, etc. into different files for organization. I'm not sure if your project is currently in one file or not, but this is general advice. This app may be a minor one, but it's good practice for larger apps to keep things organized. For example, a directory structure I would use in this case looks like this:

   ```
   src/
   ├── actions/
   │   ├── actions.js
   │   └── actionCreators.js
   ├── reducers/
   │   └── todos.js
   ├── components/
   │   └── Todos.js
   └── index.js
   ```

   Where `action.js` contains all your actions, exported using ES6 modules (which I name accordingly for uniformity):

   ```
   export const DELETE_TODO = 'DELETE_TODO';
   export const ADD_TODO = 'ADD_TODO';
   ```

   And `actionCreators.js` contains all *the action creators*, in other words, returns an action to be dispatched. Right now, you're using object literals left and right, which isn't very consistent. It also doesn't convey a message at a glance. I would use action creators instead, for example, if you're adding a todo:

   ```
   export const addTodo = text => ({
     type: ADD_TODO,
     text
   });
   ```

   Then you can dispatch the action like so:

   ```
   dispatch(addTodo('foo'));
   ```

   Instead of like this everytime:

   ```
   dispatch({ type: ADD_TODO, text: 'foo' });
   ```

   This can be applied also to another action creator named `deleteTodo`. And in this new structure, `todos.js` would be a separate file for your reducer. This is good practice in preparation for larger apps, where you may have more than one reducer. Finally `Todos.js` is your actual React component and `index.js` is where you create the store and call `ReactDOM.render`.
2. **`react-redux`** - Don't subscribe to state like that -- sure, it works but there's a more canonical pattern to use. That's where the [`react-redux`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) comes in. Redux doesn't have anything to with React itself, but *integrates* well with React with the `react-redux` package. This is because Redux emits updates (via `store.subscribe`) when you dispatch and action and generate new state, which `react-redux` can take advantage to readably *connect* your components to state without having to recall `ReactDOM.render` every time the store changes. This allows for scaling to larger applications with more components.

   So in `react-redux` there's the [`connect`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options) higher-order component that provides state to a certain child, *connect*ing it to the Redux store. You provide it two arguments: `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`. What each does can be found in more detail at the GitHub page, but they essentially take values and the `dispatch` function from the Redux store and pass them as props to a certain component, the same as what you're doing now, except all in a neat package. But `connect` has to get the store from somewhere, so `react-redux` also provides a [`<Provider>`](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#provider-store) component to pass down the Redux store to ancestors while not having to physically do `store.getState()`. This will get you this in `index.js`:

   ```
   import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
   import Todos from './components/Todos.js';
   import todos from './reducers/todos.js';

   const store = createStore(todos);

   ReactDOM.render(
     <Provider store={store}>
       <Todos />
     </Provider>,
     …
   );
   ```

   Then in `Todos.js`:

   ```
   class Todos extends React.Component {
     constructor() {
       this.state = {
         inputText: ''
       };
     }

     handleChange(e) {
       this.setState({
         inputText: e.target.value
       });
     }

     render() {
       const { todos, onAdd, onDelete } = this.props;

       return (
         <div>
           <h1>TODO!</h1>
           <ul>
             {
               todos.map(({ text }, index) => (
                 <li key={index}>
                   {text}
                   <button onClick={() => onDelete(index)}>delete</button>
                 </li>
               )
             }
             <li>
               <input type="text" value={this.state.inputText} onChange={e => this.handleChange(e)}/>
               <button onClick={() => onAdd(this.state.inputText)}>add</button>
             </li>
           </ul>
         </div>
       );
     }
   }

   const mapStateToProps = ({ todos }) => ({ todos }); //provides this.props.todos
   const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
     onAdd(text) {
       dispatch(addTodo(text)); //import this from ../actions/actionCreators.js
     },
     onDelete(index) {
       dispatch(deleteTodo(index));
     }
   });

   export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Todos); //connects component to Redux store
   ```

   Finally, this will clean up the reducer in `todos.js` for you:

   ```
   export default function todos(state = { todos: [] }, action) {
     switch(action.type) {
       case ADD_TODO: //import from ../actions/actions.js
         return {
           todos: state.todos.concat({
             text: action.text
           })
         };
       case DELETE_TODO:
         const filtered = state.todos.filter((e, index) => index !== action.index);
         return {
           todos: filtered
         };
       default:
         return state;
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you for this helpful, detailed review, Andrew! Re: `This creates lots of store dispatches and updates which are completely unnecessary and costly.`, is this statement controversial at all? In other words, would any experienced developers argue for keeping `inputText` as I have done? I'm asking to learn!

Comment: @KevinMeredith I can't say for sure, but I don't see any upside. Personally, I believe in keeping state in the narrowest scope possible, like variables in JavaScript. With your current structure, you're dispatching an action every time you input, then rerendering the component once you dispatch. This creates updates which could be removed if you manage state within the component itself. The whole reason for actions/action creators is the ability to pass in an argument (such as `action.text`) to update the store. There's no foreseeable benefit to having `inputText` in the global store.

Comment: Any idea why I'm getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` on `todos.map(({ text }, index) =>`? I typed out your helpful  answer, but I'm getting that error. Thanks!

Comment: @KevinMeredith Have you made sure you're using `mapStateToProps`?

Comment: Yes I am as I understand - https://github.com/kevinmeredith/react-counter-learning/tree/master/src.

Comment: @KevinMeredith Oh yes! This problem is quite a hard one to track down. In your initial state (in your reducer), you have an array, not an object. It should be `state = { todos: [] }` because your state is an object *with a todos array, not the todos array itself*.

Comment: I tried [that](https://github.com/kevinmeredith/react-counter-learning/commit/0fa7390ee48ce7987868e40b9d7708b70ddcb272), Andrew, but it's still showing me that same error. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: @KevinMeredith is this happening on app load? Or when a certain action occurs?

Comment: After I run the app via npm start, I navigate to localhost:3000. It shows thar error in my browser.

Comment: @KevinMeredith Another sneaky error -- You're importing `Todos` wrong in `index.js`. You're trying to import `{ Todos }` but *the connected component is the default export, not a named export* - it should be `import Todos from '...';`

Comment: Thank you very much, Andrew! For `default` versus `named` exports, does that fall under the topic of ES6? If you can recommend any books, I'd appreciate it! Thank you

Comment: @KevinMeredith Yes, it's part of the ES6 module system. The MDN documentation for [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) and [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) are good places to start. I don't know of any specific books but just reading through the documentation is good.